# Error authenticating using SMTP with gmail using JAVA MAIL

Tags: java, email, smtp, smtp-auth

I am building an JAVA application that needs to do some automated emailing. I want to automate emailing users when they have been outbid, won a bid, or an auction is close to ending.

I have experimented with using JAVA MAIL to programmatically send emails to users from a gmail email account via SMTP.

I have created a session with the following properties:

```
mailProps.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
mailProps.put("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
mailProps.put("mail.from", "example@gmail.com");
mailProps.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
mailProps.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
mailProps.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
```

This however gives the following error when it tries to connect with the gmail smtp server:

```
2017-01-14T15:10:00.437+0000|Info: DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM
2017-01-14T15:10:00.437+0000|Info: DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
2017-01-14T15:10:00.688+0000|Info: DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuw
534-5.7.14 EfaT2fDb2sjOrLupYNLlyOHb9lE38eDaz5aUiuBq92gl3
534-5.7.14 kZTEQkua_PZIUyxIdz49T58PTKSKOyzdqCX0gkcSFz6uz-lh
534-5.7.14 33n4s01a1H4jmxgJcm9tU-re9mmzW_YRno-F6DkwnVJKJVSVwYnMzxmwBE
534-5.7.14 EQrJwrflGIGvyv_ShBDkHLFwGrzf0> Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 c202sm13382879wmd.10 - gsmtp
```

The link in the error code mentions that I may need to 'Allow less secure apps: If you don't use 2-Step Verification, you might need to allow less secure apps to access your account.' It also states that this would make my account less secure, and I would like not to do that.

Do I have to use 2-step authentication, and if so could anybody point me to a resource where it is described?

Also, there are limits to sending emails via SMTP with gmail. I was wondering if this approach is the proper type of approach to use for sending notification emails from a JAVA application? Is there a way to be a trusted email sender, and increase you limits? Or am I on the wrong track here altogether

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

This link https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833 might answer your question. Look at the section "How to generate and app password". After that, you'll select an "app", say gmail, drive, etc, and then generate and "app password", for that, which you'll then use in your Java application for sending and receiving gmail.